# Force 2 NICs to specific protocol, ISCSI and SMB

Tags: iscsi, server-message-block

So i have this diskless / pxe booting environment with 28 clients.

Essentially it's 28 clients communicating using ISCSI protocol with a single diskless server.

The issue we have so far is that clients also need to read SMB based files from a different server, and when both ISCSI and SMB transfer happen at high rate,
clients gets laggy or booting failure.

To solve this i plan to use additional NIC on client,
which is assigned for SMB, while the onboard NIC should be used for ISCSI.
Is this possible using windows 7 64 ?
i will then separate the switch as well. Because overall it's still far cheaper than implementing 10G network.

I read SMB multichannel might actually be related but i still havent found any documentations about separating protocols for 2 NICs.

Comment: Hm this raises another issue for my smb server, is there anyway to force share name to use specific NIC which is intended for sharing SMB?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, i just need to disable file and printer sharing for the iscsi nic

Comment: Hmm looks like disabling file sharing does not actually disable smb, i even restarted server service, but it still allows smb share on clients.. any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put both NICs on different subnets, and make sure that the services you want to access are accessed by their appropriate IP addresses.

E.g. your iSCSI network is `10.65.101.0/24` and your SMB network is `10.65.202.0/24`.

If you're using DNS, make sure that your iSCSI server and your SMB servers *only* resolve to IP addresses in the appropriate networks. If the DNS record for those servers reports two IP addresses (one in each subnet) you can flip a coin as to which NIC gets used - which is not what you want.

Both networks will need a DHCP server (one actual DHCP server itself is fine, you'll have to either multi-home it or have a DHCP forwarder to it)

Make sure that only one NIC receives a Default Gateway, that way the client computers will know which NIC to use for accessing other networks (such as the internet).

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing, im using kabini boards a68n-5200. Would there be any issue cpu or ram wise for this sort of setup?

Comment: I've never heard of that brand or that board, but a quick google shows me that it only has a single PCIe slot. If that slot is unpopulated you'll be fine. If that slot is populated then obviously something is going to have to go.

Comment: Yeah the plan is to use that lone pcie slot for intel nic. My concern is cpu / ram (4gb) or even the board itself..  is it good enough for this sort of setup?

Comment: People have been doing that sort of setup for literally 20 years, so yeah - you’ll be fine. That said, start slowly. Buy one card and try it. If it works buy more.

Answer (score 0):

In short - yes. The simplest way is to create two different separated physical networks. Connect iSCSI server to the first one, SMB server to the second. Assign different IP networks to both segments so you will have 2 isolated networks.